# How to create one pdf combining several individual pdf plots in r

Tags: r, pdf, plot

I have a few r pdf plots that are generated individually. I want to put all these plots together and create a single pdf file containing all the plots. For example, suppose I have 6 pdf files namely "1.pdf", "2.pdf", ..., "6.pdf". I want to create a single 3x2 pdf file naming "combine.pdf" where I will have the above mentioned 6 pdf files. I searched online but all of those suggests how to put multiple plots in one pdf file which is not the answer I am looking for. I will highly appreciate a response to my question. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `merge_pdf()` in the plotflow package? The CRAN version appears to be obsolete but you can get it from the [GitHub repos](https://github.com/trinker/plotflow) with: `devtools::install_github("trinker/plotflow")`. Perhaps there is a good reason to do it after the .pdf are created but `layout` may help create such a combined plot from your individual plots.